# finally block in tornado gen engine not works

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, tornado, finally

Suppose, (using tornado) one wants to transfer a big data to a slow client, and prints the amount of data transfered. I wrote this simple code for this purpose:

```
from tornado import web, ioloop, gen

class MainHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    @web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        print '( start'
        try:
            for i in xrange(100):
                self.write('*' * 100000)  # write ~100KB of data
                yield gen.Task(self.flush)  # wait for reciever to recieve
                print '- wrote', i
        finally:
            print '| finally'
            self.finish()
        print ') finish'

application = web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

application.listen(8888)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But this code is not working as expected, e.g. with this simple client:

```
req = urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8888/')
sys.exit()  # exit without reading response
```

Server outputs this:

```
( start
- wrote 0
- wrote 1
- wrote 2
WARNING:root:Read error on 7: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
WARNING:root:error on read
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 361, in _handle_read
    if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 428, in _read_to_buffer
    chunk = self._read_from_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 409, in _read_from_socket
    chunk = self.socket.recv(self.read_chunk_size)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

but neither `finally` nor `finish` is printed.

What's the problem?!

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that if I implement `on_connection_close` for handler, the `on_connection_close` callback will be called, and no error is printed in console. But what the magic this function is? (I already defined on `RequestHandler` with empty body).

And bigger answer: why my generator is not `close`d? It's garbage collected or not? PEP-342 says that finally block should be executed in any situation.

Comment: I suppose the generator is still waiting for more input?

Comment: @Martijn The finally block won't run even if I close the server with signal (or Control+C). How I can force finally block to execute?

Comment: I suspect it *does* run, but that `stdout` by that time has been closed already. Did you try opening an explicit, dedicated file to test?

Comment: No, tested with `open` and `write`, and finally did not run.

Comment: Interesting and confusing. I cannot provoke Python not to run the finally stuite in a generator whatever I try.

Answer (score 1):

Generators with `finally` clauses are implemented using `__del__` in Python versions <= 3.3, and have all the limitations of other destructors - they are not guaranteed to be executed promptly if at all in the presence of reference cycles.  In Python 3.4 this is improved (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/) and generator's finally clauses are run much more reliably.